# Android customized calendar view with each date cell style configurable?

Tags: java, android, calendar, calendarview

I want to add an Calendar view, Which should be capable of doing following things :

1] Highlight an range of dates,

2] Overlay an image over a date cell,

3] Change color of the date cell,

I guess this is not possible with default CalendarView of Android. (I will be happy if someone proves it wrong, if there is way of doing above things with default CalendarView of Android)

So is there any open source customized calendar view library, or project for android which is capable of doing above things.

Comment: Does anyone know any library that extend Android's `CalendarView` which allows easy customization for Date's cell drawable? I see many suggested libraries but they implement their own Calendar View which aren't extending from Android's `CalendarView`.

Answer (score 2):

here is the best customized calendar library 
https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid

cheers